# Laravel 5.8 redirect with error not showing message

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8 with custom authentication and because of that, I need to use *Cache Tags*. 
To make it work, my `CACHE_DRIVE` is set as `array`.

But with this configuration, I can't make flash session messages work when redirect to the view.

In CustomAuthController.php I've tried:

```
return redirect()
       ->route('login')
       ->withErrors('The credentials do not match our records');

OR

return redirect()->route('login')->with('error','The credentials do not match our records');
```

In login.blade.php results the same:

```
<?php print '<pre>'; print_r(session()->all()); ?>
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [_token] => yyUtSaFx3AxPrJR0biJ5HmjyHU0r5PYY0xi4kLGK
    [_previous] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://127.0.0.1:8001
        )
    [_flash] => Array (
            [old] => Array()
            [new] => Array()
        )
)
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    // Authentication Routes...
    Route::get('/', 'Auth\CustomAuthController@showLoginForm');

    Route::name('login')->get('login', 'Auth\CustomAuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::name('login')->post('login', 'Auth\CustomAuthController@login');
    Route::name('logout')->get('logout', 'Auth\CustomAuthController@logout');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::name('home')->any('home', 'HomeController@home');
    });
});
```

Anyone could help please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check that you have the web middleware group in all the routes involved or you risk to miss the StartSession middleware.

Comment: @dparoli I updated my question with the routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try-

In **CustomAuthController.php**:

```
return redirect()->route('login')->withErrors(['error' => 'The credentials do not match our records']);
```

In **login.blade.php**:

```
<p>{{session('errors')->first('error');}}</p>
```

Comment: I received this error `Undefined variable: error (View: /var/www/html/gobrax-fleetmoney/resources/views/login.blade.php)`

Comment: I updated the answer. Please try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you @Rashed Hasan!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return redirect()->route('login')->with(['error' => 'The credentials do not match our records']);
```